# PDO prepare statement fires an error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am migrating from mysql to PDO. I am creating a function, but when calling get error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in file * on line **
```

Not sure how to handle this type of migration when I have "e.match_id = '$row1->match_id'" stuff. Code with old mysql:

```
$query11 = "SELECT COUNT(e.event_id) as numgoals
FROM event e 
WHERE (e.match_id = '$row1->match_id' AND e.team_id = '$row1->team_a_id' AND e.eventtype IN ('soc_G','soc_PG') ) OR
      (e.match_id = '$row1->match_id' AND e.team_id = '$row1->team_b_id' AND e.eventtype = 'soc_OG' )";
$result11 = mysql_query($querye11);
$row11 = mysql_fetch_object($result11);
```

Function with PDO:

```
public function getResult11($row)
    {
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(e.event_id) as numgoals
                    FROM event e 
                    WHERE (e.match_id = '?->match_id' AND e.team_id = '?->team_a_id' AND e.eventtype IN ('soc_G','soc_PG') ) OR
                          (e.match_id = '?->match_id' AND e.team_id = '?->team_b_id' AND e.eventtype = 'soc_OG' )";
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute(array($row));
        return $statement->fetchObject();
    }
```

How to convert "e.match_id = '$row1->match_id'" to change "$row1" with function parameter? I used this "e.match_id = '?->match_id'", but not sure if it is right.

Comment: Show us what is in `$row`

Comment: This `'?->match_id' ` is NOT the right syntax. Do you want named parameter i.e. `:match_id` or positional parameters i.e. `?`

Comment: `$row` is another query. Not sure, I will use that fits the best my case.

Answer (score -1):

You are using variables in string wrong:

`SELECT $match->match_id` will convert only `$math` and leaves `->match_id` untouched.

Use `{}` around variable:

```
SELECT {$match->match_id}
```

**Proper user of prepared statement**

```
$query = "[...] WHERE (e.match_id = :mId AND e.team_id = :t1Id AND e.eventtype IN ('soc_G','soc_PG')) OR
                      (e.match_id = :mId AND e.team_id = :t2Id AND e.eventtype = 'soc_OG')";
$statement = $this->db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute([
    ':mId' => $row1->team_a_id,
    ':t1Id' => $row1->team_a_id,
    ':t2Id' => $row1->team_b_id,
]);
```

**If used in loop**

```
$statement = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = :id");

foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $statement->execute([
        ':id' => $id,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing the `?` I think he is just a little confused

Comment: If I have `$row1->match_id`, `$row1->team_a_id`, `$row1->team_b_id` I want them all to get same row1. Should I use 3 parameters?

Comment: @Sagi In `execute` you just pass associated array with structure `':param' => "Actual value"`

Comment: I want to call function `$row11 = $storage_access->getResult11($row1);` But not sure how should I do in case of you code. Any idea?

Comment: @Justinas is that case safe from injections? I mean If I do not specify parameters and call like `$row11 = $storage_access->getAbfrage11();`

Comment: @Sagi Properly using PDO will prevent injections

Comment: @Justinas It does not fire any error, but instead of result I get `0`. DB connection works, not sure where is the problem.